# How do I make arrows spin around me facing outward? (minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make arrows behave like spinning knifes (from [ETG](https://enterthegungeon.fandom.com/wiki/Knife_Shield)) but nothing I do seems to work and the arrows don't face where they are facing

The commands I tried to use:
command that kinda works:
`execute as @e[type=arrow,tag=knife] at @p facing entity @p feet run tp @s ^0.3 ^ ^0.03`
commands that don't work:

```
execute as @e[type=arrow,tag=knife] at @p run tp @s ^ ^ ^-1 ~ 0
execute as @e[type=arrow,tag=knife] at @s facing entity @p eyes run tp @s ^ ^ ^4 facing entity @p
execute as @e[type=minecraft:arrow,tag=knife] at @s facing entity @p feet run tp @s ^0.3 ^ ^
```

Comment: As a side-note, I'd love to do this in Bedrock edition 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I am supposed to answer my own question, but I have soooooooo:
First summon an armor stand with a special tag, so it can be easily selected:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["knife"]}
```

Then you want to spin the armor stand on a repeating command block (the rest of the command block on chain, unconditional, and always active), then make the arrows follow the rotation of the armor stand, and then go to the player, and move foward (with carrot things: ^ ^ ^) (spinning arrows themselves don't rotate correctly idk why, nor do they face the direction they appear to be facing):

```
execute as @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,tag=knife] at @s run tp @s ~ ~ ~ ~2 0
execute as @e[type=minecraft:arrow,tag=knife] at @s run tp @e[type=armor_stand,tag=knife,limit=1]
execute as @e[type=arrow,tag=knife] at @p run tp @s ~ ~ ~
execute as @e[type=arrow,tag=knife] at @s run tp ^ ^ ^3
```

This will not do damage to anything it touches, but you can make it do damage with

but I have not figured it out yet, also using this method will NOT deal damage to players